# How do I add a value next to another value in dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some text with tags on each word. This is how the text looks like:

```
text = "Wednesday/PROPN evening/NOUN to/PART reject/VERB a/DET no/DET -/PUNCT deal/NOUN Brexit/PROPN under/ADP any/DET circumstances/NOUN ./PUNCT No/DET date/NOUN has/VERB yet/ADV ./PUNCT Saturday/NOUN"
```

I want to collect all NOUN AND PROPN frequencies that stands right after the PUNCT-tag in a list. I have a dict, but I want to separate the values that I need and add it to a list. So far the code looks like this:

```js
dictionary = {}
for w in text1:
    words = w.split('/')
    dictionary[words[0]] = words[1]
    
dictlist = []
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if value == "PUNCT" #HERE is the problem. I want something like this: If the value is PUNCT and NOUN is the next value then append it to the list
        temp = [key, value]
        temp.append(temp)
```

Hope you understand my problem!

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: to clarify, it may be helpful to add an example of a dict that you want as your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain NOUN AND PROPN frequencies that stands right after the PUNCT-tag in a list you can use the following code without the need of dictionaries.

```
word_tag_list = [word.split('/') for word in text.split(' ')]

propn_freq, noun_freq = [], []

for i, word_tag in enumerate(word_tag_list):
    if word_tag[1] == "PUNCT" and i + 1 < len(word_tag_list):
        next_tag = word_tag_list[i + 1][1]
        if next_tag == "NOUN": noun_freq.append(word_tag_list[i + 1])
        elif next_tag == "PROPN": propn_freq.append(word_tag_list[i + 1])
```

If I understand correctly this will yield the desired output

```
>>> noun_freq
[['deal', 'NOUN'], ['Saturday', 'NOUN']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You understood my problem and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are not ordered in versions of Python previous to 3.7, therefore even if you put two new key-value pairs into a dictionary one after another they will not appear next to each other in the dictionary.  One option to add ordered dictionaries in python is the OrderedDict data structure in the collections module, or update Python.

```
import collections
dictionary = collections.OrderedDict()
# The rest of your code here
```